# Windows 98: cброс программ по умолчанию

Tags: windows

Имеем виртуальную машину Win-98 в VirtualBox-е. В ней файлы типа ".obj" по умолчанию открывается программой "Мой компьютер". Переустанавливать из-за этого виртуалку крайне не желательно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Предупреждение:** неаккуратная работа в редакторе реестра может нарушить работу операционной системы.

Самый короткий путь - просто удалить раздел, соответствующий нужному расширению через редактор реестра.

Нужно открыть редактор реестра (в главном меню, в разделе "Стандартные" или "Системные", или через пункт "Выполнить" по имени `regedit.exe`).

В дереве слева открыть раздел ("папку") `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, в ней найти "папку" с расширением файла (`.obj`) и удалить ее через контекстно меню.

Рандомный скриншот редактора реестра из интернета:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Принцип один и тот же практически для всех версий Windows как минимум начиная с Windows 98 (возможно, Windows 95). С Windows 11 не работал, но скорее всего там редактор реестра выглядит примерно так же, и раздел `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` и информацией об ассоциациях файлов никуда не делся.